# Issue AVSpeechUtterance

Tags: objective-c, iphone, avspeechsynthesizer

I´m trying to make the AVSpeech speak up two NSString in the string *combine and pas it to AVSpeech. But it´s only *speekone that get passed to the *combine string. So I only ge the first string spoken. Am I declaring the string wrong somehow or do I need to change my method?

```
- (IBAction)UIButtonPlayPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
NSString *speekone = _activity.activityName;
NSString *speektwo = _activity.activityDescription;
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:speekone, speektwo];

if (speechPaused == NO) {
//Title for button    [self.UIButtonPlay setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.synthesizer continueSpeaking];
    speechPaused = YES;
    NSLog(@"playing");
} else {
//Titleforbutton    [self.UIButtonPlay setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    speechPaused = NO;
    [self.synthesizer pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
    NSLog(@"paused");

}
if (self.synthesizer.speaking == NO) {
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:combined];
[self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to your `stringWithFormat` is not a format specifier.

This line:

```
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:speekone, speektwo];
```

should become:

```
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", speekone, speektwo];
```